# Box2D in Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, kobold2d

I am currently running Kobold 1.0.4 and cannot work out how to use Box2D using Objective-C, any help will be appreciated.
I have looked at the Box2d example project with kobold but it uses only c++ i need to do it in objective-c as i am not really confident playing with both.

Comment: This question is a bit broad.  Anything Specific you need to accomplish?  As a sidenote ObjC++ is quite powerful.

Comment: Try the Box2D Objective-C wrapper 'Boxjective2D' in KoboldTouch: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/KTD/Objective-C+Physics+Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change extension of your source files from *.m to *.mm to be able to use c++ classes in them. It will allow you to create and manage box2d objects in your objective-c code

Comment: Ive tried this and it seems to be working well but there is no code completion and its hard to see how to actually use box2d. Thanks this has helped me.

Comment: box2d has good reference. it is rather well documented. for example, http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

Box2D is written in C++ so one way or another there's no getting around it. Since Box2D's code does the heavy-lifting, the amount of C++ code needed to us it is quite small, you just need to get the boilerplate up for collision handlers and then the code you fill it with can be as objective-C as you want.

If you want something that helps get geometry into your app, [PhysicsEditor](http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor) is a good tool and they have a plist exporter and provide an objective-C class for loading the data. It takes care of a lot of boilerplate, and if you want to do collision geometry for anything interesting it's very helpful.